# What could be the most appropriate ordering in data preparation?

Tags: data-transformation, econometrics, data-preprocessing

Are there any references in the literature on what is (or could be) the appropriate oredering of actions taken in the data preparation stage:

1. deflating (nominal to real)
2. transformations (log, square root, power...)
3. seasonal adjustment
4. temporal disaggregation

Or is there an objective reason why some step should be taken prior to another step and not vice versa

Answer (score 0):

I have this same question. The best answer I've found so far is another CrossValidated answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/data-preparation-for-regression).